# Java script Validation on an html form in not working?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I coded an HTML form where I tried to validate it using javascript, However, the validation doesn't work. It should work on click of submit button. Everything looks fine! could not find the error! Please Help.
Below is the code for the page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Term Deposit Interest Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
 <script>  
function validateform(){  
var amount=document.myform.amount.value;  
var years=document.myform.years.value; 
var interst= document.myform.interst.value; 

if (amount==null || amount==""){  
  alert("Amount can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}else if (years==null || years==""){  
  alert("Years can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}else if (interest==null || interest==""){  
  alert("Interest can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}

}  
</script>  

</head>

<body>

  <div class="card">
    <h3>Term Deposit Interest Calculator</h3><br>
  <form name = "myform"  method="post"onsubmit="return validateform()">
    <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Deposit Amount"><span id="num1"></span>
    <input type="text" name="years" placeholder="Number Of Years"><span id="num2"></span>
    <input type="text" name="interest" placeholder="Yearly Interst Rate"><span id="num3"></span>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="my submit" value="Total Amount">
  </form>

  <div class="result">

  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
<?php
if (!isset($amount7032)) { $amount7032 = ''; }
if (!isset($interest7032)) { $interest7032 = ''; }
if (!isset($years7032)) { $years7032 = ''; }
?>
```

Comment: Throw some console.logs into your code and find out where it is going wrong. In the future, try to avoid saying "It doesn't work" without giving an explanation of what does happen vs what is expected. It helps us to help you.

Comment: You have a spelling mistake in your code for one of your field names. Open up your javascript console and tell it to not clear the log on navigation ("Preserve Log" in Chrome). The console would have then kept the error visible

Comment: @steve Thanks! I will next time :)

Comment: @PatrickEvans I Figured! Thanks for the trick, Will Enable the log option in my chrome next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong form element name at below line

```
var interst= document.myform.interst.value;
```

it should be

```
var interest= document.myform.interest.value;
```

Basically because javascript was not able to find the form element and it was failing due to that.

I tried below code and its working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Term Deposit Interest Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        function validateform(){  
        var amount=document.myform.amount.value;  
        var years=document.myform.years.value; 
        var interest= document.myform.interest.value; 

        if (amount==null || amount==""){  
          alert("Amount can't be blank");  
          return false;  
        }else if (years==null || years==""){  
          alert("Years can't be blank");  
          return false;  
        }else if (interest==null || interest==""){  
          alert("Interest can't be blank");  
          return false;  
        }

        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="card">
        <h3>Term Deposit Interest Calculator</h3><br>
        <form name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateform()">
            <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Deposit Amount"><span id="num1"></span>
            <input type="text" name="years" placeholder="Number Of Years"><span id="num2"></span>
            <input type="text" name="interest" placeholder="Yearly Interst Rate"><span id="num3"></span>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="my submit" value="Total Amount">
        </form>

        <div class="result">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is a close vote for questions that are solved by fixing a typo.

Comment: Thanks! I figured, These minor mistakes are hard to find!